# Given a liquid or gas environment, would radial symmetry be an advantage over bilateral?

Tags: alien-geometry

Europa, Jupiter or small planets offer different environments and gravity for alien life to evolve.  I see many advantages to life possessing radial symmetry in both lower and higher gravity environments.  What advantages and disadvantages would be pertinent to this form of life.

Comment: Bilateral symmetry evolved in the seas of Earth, and I expect that it would evolve in the seas of Titan too.  Which is not to say that Titanic jellyfish and starfish wouldn't exist, but I wouldn't expect then to be any more dominant than they are here.

Comment: There's quite a few [liquid environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean) here on Earth, and we certainly have critters with [radial symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_biology#Radial_symmetry) but they are far from dominant. Why do you believe that radial symmetry would have many advantages in higher/lower gravity?

Answer (score 7):

I think you can look for an answer in Ediacaran biota, which, as far as I'm aware, lived exclusively in fluid environment. Just browsing through the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ediacaran_genera), there were a number of radially symmetric genera, but there is also bilateral and even tri-lobed symmetry.

Of course, Ediacaran seas are were shallow, and the fact that there was a bottom to be reached must have had a definite impact on morphology: if you can attach to something, or lie or browse along the bottom, that's a very different lifestyle than if you have thousands of kilometres of hydrogen atmosphere in every direction.

The benefits of bilateral body plan are organ specialization and mobility. Radial form lets you react to opportunities and threats from many directions. In other words, if you can predict where your lunch is coming from, go bilateral. If all directions are equally likely, radial is best. The same applies to others taking a bite out of you.

Would you have consciousness develop in radially symmetric creatures? I imagine that would produce vastly different minds from our own.

Answer (score 0):

Bilateral symmetry seems like the natural result of having multiple axes to deal with. In life on Earth, those axes were the vertical and oral-aboral axes. If there is no vertical axis, then life would be radial, which is life with only a single axis

Comment: Yes, but actually even one layer deeper. It there were *no* differentiation between directions, not even gravity, then some form of spherical symmetry would prevail. But gravity, and lightsource, almost always play a role. For any mobile organism, there is also a preferred "front" and "back". And it's a good idea to put specialized organs on the correct orientation. Eye and mouth work better on the front. Propulsion and excretion work better on the back. But for an immoble/floating organism, in an environment with no directionality at all? spherical symmetry., or even none.

Comment: @PcMan Many animals in this realm would still have to move, which would provide the front-back axis required for radial life

Answer (score 0):

### It's your call.

Pelagic and benthic organisms in Earth's oceans can display radial or bilateral symmetry.  Both symmetries are viable.  Both are plausible for life on another world.

Don't assume that one or the other will be favored based on "simplicity".  For example, echinoderms develop from a bilateral larva.  If you pick up a starfish you'll see one feature, the madreporite, which is *not* radially symmetric, even in the adult.  Some sea cucumbers, also members of that group, have returned to a sort of bilateral symmetry, with differences between their radial sectors.  This develops completely independently of their embryonic bilateral symmetry.

The lifestyle and evolutionary history of the organisms gives you free rein for your creativity.